# Write down a function that squares any number and, if possible, takes the reciprocal

Tags: calculus

I need to write down a function that that squares any number and, if possible, takes the reciprocal of that number.

This is what I have done:

$f(x)=x^{2}$

and

$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Then

$(f\circ g)(x)=(\frac{1}{x})^{2}=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Is correct my interpretation of the problem statement?

Comment: "*and*, **if possible**, *takes the reciprocal of that number*"  What if it is not possible?  What should the function do then?  When is it not possible to take the reciprocal of a number?

Comment: Once one write down the required function it is required to determine if that function is invertible.

Comment: I think my solution is not correct because in the next part of the entire problem it is required to define a subset of the domain where the restriction of this function is actually going to be invertible.

Comment: Then before continuing, you need to tell what is the domain and the codomain for the function.  Also, for it to be a *function* in the *first place* you need to clarify what happens if taking the reciprocal is allowed or not.  Is this a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ (and what happens at zero?)  Is this a function from $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ to $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$?  From $\Bbb R^+$ to $\Bbb R^+$?  From $[5,\infty)$ to $(0,\frac{1}{25}]$?

Comment: It can be invertible, depending, on some domains/codomains and not on others.  What would make it not be invertible?  Have you heard the terms "injection" and "surjection" before?  What about the terms "onto" and "one-to-one"?

Comment: I know the domain for the function $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ is $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and its range is $\mathbb{R^{+}}$.

Comment: That is one possible domain, but that is not its *only* possible domain.  A function not only describes how to map an input to an output, but it also has as a fundamental piece of information about itself what its domain is and what its codomain is.  That may be the largest subset of $\Bbb R$ which acts as a domain for the function you describe, but nothing apart from something given in the problem statement or your own assumptions is requiring that be the actual official domain for the function.

Comment: @JMoravitz, is it correct my definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40566/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-john-ortiz-ordonez).

Answer (score 1):

It is OK, except IMHO it should be $g \circ f$ (for style, the values are the same).

Comment: Yes, it more directly implements what was asked for.